# Android native file read from assets folder by tflite BuildFromFile()

Tags: android, c++, tensorflow, android-ndk, tensorflow-lite

I have Android native code (`C++` shared object), that want to `read` model file kept in the `assets` folder while creating APK.

Tensorflow Lite has two APIs: FromFile and FromBuffer

```
static std::unique_ptr<FlatBufferModel> BuildFromFile(const char* filename, ErrorReporter* error_reporter);

static std::unique_ptr<FlatBufferModel> BuildFromBuffer(const char* buffer, size_t buffer_size, ErrorReporter* error_reporter);
```

with following code i can access FromBuffer:

`Java` code:

```
private AssetManager mgr;

// Get mgr 
mgr = getResources().getAssets();
```

`C++` code:

```
AAssetDir* assetDir = AAssetManager_openDir(mgr, "");
const char* filename = (const char*)NULL;
while ((filename = AAssetDir_getNextFileName(assetDir)) != NULL) {
    AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, filename, AASSET_MODE_STREAMING);
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    int nb_read = 0;
    FILE* out = fopen(filename, "w");
    while ((nb_read = AAsset_read(asset, buf, BUFSIZ)) > 0)
        fwrite(buf, nb_read, 1, out);
    fclose(out);
    AAsset_close(asset);
}
AAssetDir_close(assetDir);
```

Any ideas, how can access `assets` folder to use `BuildFromFile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use `BuildFromFile` without copying the asset file to a local file (which is equivalent to what you've done above, and then `BuildFromBuffer` is more convenient in this case).

If you want to avoid memory copy, here is what you can do:

1. (Java) Load the model through memory mapping.

```
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = getResources().getAssets().openFd(filePath);\
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());\
    FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();\
    long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();\
    long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();\
    MappedByteBuffer modelBuffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
```

2. (Java) Pass the mapped file to C++ through jni, such as defining the following method:

```
    private static native void initJniWithByteBuffer(ByteBuffer modelBuffer)
```

3. (C++) Use the buffer file to initialize you model:

```
    Java_xxxxxx_initJniWithByteBuffer(JNIEnv* env, jclass thiz, jobject model_buffer) {\
      char* buffer = static_cast<char*>(env->GetDirectBufferAddress(model_buffer));\
      size_t buffer_size = static_cast<size_t>(env->GetDirectBufferCapacity(model_buffer));\
    }
```

Comment: Worked for me, with one caveat: if you store the mapping pointer on the C++ side and reuse it later, make sure to keep the `MappedByteBuffer` Java object around for as long as you need the pointer.